# Multiple puppetmaster behind load balancer

Tags: linux, puppet, openstack, haproxy

We build two puppet master on `openstack` cloud and put them behind `LBaasV2` (haproxy) load balancer, also we have separate puppetDB and PuppetCA server to handle certificate.

```
                        |----[puppetmaster1]
   [Agent]-----[LB]-----|  
                        |----[puppetmaster2]
```

now problem is when i am running `puppet agent -t -v` it does sending certificate sign request to `puppetCA` server but after running second time puppet agent getting following error

```
 [root@agent ~]# puppet agent -t -v
 Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
 Warning: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A
 Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
 Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A
```

Does `LB` messing with SSL certificate? Or does it related to puppetDB issue. I haven't seen any document or any related article to setup puppet in cluster using LB.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

I found issue and you won't believe it was network `MTU` size issue.

Openstack VM use MTU `1400` default and rest of the world use MTU `1500`

As soon as i change MTU 1400 on puppet client machine it works! But not sure why openstack use 1400 there must be a reason.